# What was the character that cried "jabba jabba" in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi, ewoks

In the *Star Wars* trilogy, at some point a minor character cried/grunted something like "jabba jabba" (no relationship to the Hutt) or "joba joba". I believe this was in reaction to something the droids, in particular R2D2, did. Apparently it meant something like "have to go back to work". I don't believe it was an Ewok, but something similar. Which character was it and where in the movie (link would be awesome)?

Comment: In another context, this might seem obsessive, but here, this is what we do - why not watch the trilogy and track it down?

Comment: I will surely answer my own question when I watch that part :)

Comment: I know the Ewoks say "jub jub" a lot, is it possible that's what you're thinking?

Comment: @Jason - Yub Yub is the official translitertion for Ewok

Comment: Yes, now I come to think of it, it could very well be the "jubba jubba jubbu" at the Golden God scene, as translated on http://www.wattpad.com/15840601-star-wars-vi-the-return-of-the-jedi-chapter-xxv/page/2. I'll have to double check in the movie.

Comment: I know this was long ago answered and accepted, but isn't it also possible that it was a Jawa?

Comment: IIRC, the eyeball droid on the gate of Jabba's palace says to C3PO something to the effect of "Ee choba!"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're almost certainly referring to scene 71 and scene 72 in [ROTJ](http://www.wattpad.com/15840601-star-wars-vi-the-return-of-the-jedi-chapter-xxv/page/2).

Logray the Ewok says "*Jubba Jubba Jubbo*" just after Solo says "*He's an old friend of mine*" at 1:12:00.

He repeats the same sound (it may actually be the same sound-clip) in the 'Golden God' scene, just after C3P0 threatens to make the village go boom at 1:14:32.

It appears to indicate something like '**let's get on with it**'.

Comment: And, how exactly did you find that? I can't believe you have got that strong memory.

Comment: @sachinshekar - If memory serves, JasonBaker gave me the first clue in the comments above

Comment: @Valorum - it's not that you were a fan of the Ewoks animated TV series, where this kind of vocalisation appeared quite a lot, then? :)

Comment: @Jules - The Ewoks show was bloody brilliant, as was Caravan of Courage (which I saw in the cinema).